# android motionlayout swipe sometimes not working

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

First of all, I am not good at English. please understand

ExoPlayer + MotionLayout

1. The fragment is exposed when the adapter is clicked in the source
2. At the time of exposure, the motion layout is sent to the end to enlarge the screen.
3. If you do 2step  after defining the fragment when clicking the adapter, it does not work when you slowly swipe the screen again.
4. As in the source below, instead of hiding the fragment, lower the y-axis to make it invisible and then click the adapter.
   In this case, even if you swipe slowly, the motionlayout will work.

The difference between 3 and 4 is when you use the supportFragmentManager
or The difference is whether it is hidden by the Y-axis or hidden by view properties.

I really want to know why.

**Success Code**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainMotionLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene"
    tools:context=".view.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/mainBottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/mainRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

**activity_main_scene.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="1000">
        <KeyFrameSet></KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            >> android:translationY="70dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"  />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/mainBottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/mainBottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:translationY="56dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"  />

    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

**fragment_player.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.jschoi.develop.aop_part03_chapter08.CustomVideoMotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/playerMotionLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/fragment_player_scene">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContainerLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.github.vkay94.dtpv.DoubleTapPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/playerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:dtpv_controller="@id/youtube_overlay"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/mainContainerLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/mainContainerLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/mainContainerLayout"
        app:resize_mode="fill" />

    <com.github.vkay94.dtpv.youtube.YouTubeOverlay
        android:id="@+id/youtube_overlay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/playerView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/playerView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/playerView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/playerView"
        app:yt_playerView="@id/playerView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bottomPlayerControlButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_play_arrow_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/mainContainerLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/mainContainerLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/mainContainerLayout" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomTitleTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/bottomPlayerControlButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/bottomPlayerControlButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/playerView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bottomPlayerControlButton" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mainContainerLayout" />
</com.jschoi.develop.aop_part03_chapter08.CustomVideoMotionLayout>
```

**fragment_player_scene.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.jschoi.develop.aop_part03_chapter08.CustomVideoMotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/playerMotionLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/fragment_player_scene">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContainerLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.github.vkay94.dtpv.DoubleTapPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/playerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:dtpv_controller="@id/youtube_overlay"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/mainContainerLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/mainContainerLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/mainContainerLayout"
        app:resize_mode="fill" />

    <com.github.vkay94.dtpv.youtube.YouTubeOverlay
        android:id="@+id/youtube_overlay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/playerView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/playerView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/playerView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/playerView"
        app:yt_playerView="@id/playerView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bottomPlayerControlButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_play_arrow_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/mainContainerLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/mainContainerLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/mainContainerLayout" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomTitleTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/bottomPlayerControlButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/bottomPlayerControlButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/playerView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bottomPlayerControlButton" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mainContainerLayout" />
</com.jschoi.develop.aop_part03_chapter08.CustomVideoMotionLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val activityMainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        mainBinding = activityMainBinding

        setContentView(activityMainBinding.root)

        fragment = PlayerFragment()
        retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance()
        videoAdapter = VideoAdapter(callback = { url, title ->
            supportFragmentManager.fragments.find { it is PlayerFragment }?.let {
                (it as PlayerFragment).play(url, title)
                >> fragment.animation()
            }
        })

        mainBinding.mainRecyclerView.apply {
            adapter = videoAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
        }


>>        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
            .commit()

        getVideoList()
    }
```

**PlayerFragment**

```
 fun animation() {
        binding?.playerMotionLayout?.post {
            binding?.playerMotionLayout?.transitionToEnd()
        }
    }
```

**Fail Source**